# Generate a secure password

Tags: code-challenge

## Task

Your task is to generate a password that is both secure and short in the fewest bytes possible given an integer seed as input.

## Input

No seed
Or
An integer seed

## Output

A password

## Scoring

Your score is how many seconds the password takes to crack on [How secure is my password](https://howsecureismypassword.net/) divided by (bytes * password length)

Scoring is unbalanced because this is for fun

Comment: Surely the score needs to be for a specific seed? Otherwise it will vary depending on the seed...

Comment: It would probably have been more interesting with a maximum length for the password (such as 32 characters), to prevent the infinite score from being reached.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's really a question of the length of the output.  Without more details or restrictions, it's just a "generate infinite output" challenge.

Comment: @Brzyrt You should probably use the Sandbox to test questions before posting, this feels half-baked.

Comment: Given that the output is supposed to be random or depend on the input seed, which output(s) are used for scoring?

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), ∞

Full program. Does not need a seed.

```apl
⎕AV
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKO94P@jvqmOYSDmfwUwKAAA)

`⎕AV` is the **A**tomic **V**ector, i.e. the code page: `` "\u0000\b\n\r \f\u0006\u0007\u001B\t⌶ɫ%'⍺⍵_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz\u0001\u0002¯.⍬0123456789\u0003⊢¥$£¢∆ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ\u0004\u0005ý·⍙ÁÂÃÇÈÊËÌÍÎÏÐÒÓÔÕÙÚÛÝþãìðòõ{€}⊣⌷¨ÀÄÅÆ⍨ÉÑÖØÜßàáâäåæçèéêëíîïñ[/⌿\\⍀<≤=≥>≠∨∧-+÷×?∊⍴~↑↓⍳○*⌈⌊∇∘(⊂⊃∩∪⊥⊤|;,⍱⍲⍒⍋⍉⌽⊖⍟⌹!⍕⍎⍫⍪≡≢óôöø\"#\u001E&´┘┐┌└┼─├┤┴┬│@ùúû^ü`∣¶:⍷¿¡⋄←→⍝)]\u001F §⎕⍞⍣" ``

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), Infinite score.

Gets `Forever` on the password generator. So score is Infinite.

```
žĆ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//6L4jbf//AwA)

Comment: Why can't I type it @a'_'

Comment: Yeah, a bit of ALT-code never hurt anybody.

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 11 bytes, score = Infinity

An evil password.

```
_=>1n<<666n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/e1s4wz8bGzMws739yfl5xfk6qXk5@ukaahqbmfwA)

Generates:

```
306180206916083902309240650087602475282639486413866622577088471913520022894784390350900738
050555138105234536857820245071373614031482942161565170086143298589738273508330367307539078
392896587187265470464n
```

The final '**n**' in the output is what makes *howsecureismypassword.net* believe that there are enough distinct characters for this to take forever to crack.

Without it, it would take only 79,220,219,535,072,410,000,000,000,000 quinquagintillion years. :-)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>19</s> 6 bytes, Score: Inf

Whopping -13 thanks to @a'_'

```python
help()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PyM1p0BD8/9/AA)

Comment: Finally an answer that I can golf! [6 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PyM1p0BD8/9/YwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [SOGL V0.12](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGLOnline), 1 [byte](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md), score: Infinity

Since we can't win 05AB1E, what about a shorter solution? This program basically yields the full SOGL code page.

```
█
```

[Try it Here!](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=JXUyNTg4,v=0.12)

Comment: Ahaha! That is very funny indeed. I like how this challenge devolved from "who can generate a good random password" to "who can print the weirdest gobbledygook in the fewest characters".

Answer (score 0):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 4 bytes, score = Infinity

An evil password.

```
74,`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/39xEJ@H/fwA)

Generates:

```
[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73]
```

The final '**`**' is what makes *howsecureismypassword.net* believe that there are enough distinct characters for this to take forever to crack.

Without it, it would take only 79,220,219,535,072,370 quinquagintillion years. :-)

Answer (score 0):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 5 bytes, Score = Inf

```
+[+.]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fO1pbL/b/fwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 10 bytes -> Infinite score

```php
phpinfo();
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAkgTgzLy1fQ9P6/38A)

Basically a kind of port of @SurculoseSputum's python answer